# Generating and embedding resources at build time in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build, build-process, embedded-resource

***The core of my question is***:
How can I embed a resource created by some process which is run at build-time in MS Visual Studio 2010.

***The details and motivation for this problem are are***:
We have an in-house scripting language. Each project contains scripts in this language which need to undergo some preprocessing before being embedded.

Although this probably has no bearing on the answer to this question, I ought to mention just in case that the processing cannot be done one file at a time. A part of this preprocessing is dependency and version management which requires the script processor to not only to know about all of the scripts in the current project but also the scripts in any projects it depends upon.

Each source script file produces one script file to be embedded so I could manually create empty files, set them to be embedded resources and then have the script processor over-write them, however I would much rather not have to do this and in the future it is likely that there will not be a simple one-to-one mapping of source to output so this won't be possible.

The script preprocessor is itself a visual studio project, so can be included in the project as such if required rather than simply being run as a command-line tool if that helps in any way.

***Closing remarks***:
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated, I don't necessarily expect anyone to give me a complete solution. I am very new to Visual Studio. The project is in VB but if answers involve code I really don't mind what language you use.

Comment: mananged resources (compiled into MSIL) or native resource?

Comment: Either I don't understand your question or you don't understand mine. Certainly they are not compiled to MSIL, they are just text file so far as dotNET is concerned. In order to manually embed the files I set the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" -- I hope that makes it clear